# Change read_proc_t read_proc and write_proc_t write_proc of an existing file in /proc

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm actually working lkm on linux 2.6.32, and I don't to understand one thing. I'm trying to change the original read_proc and write_proc of /proc/version with my functions. Thus I can to change the original value of read_proc and write_proc, with values of my function. I can see it, because values of read_proc and write_proc change to NULL to adress of my functions, but that have no effect... And I don't understand why. I don't arrive to find if version is protected (I tried to change the value of file's right with chmod), or why even after change the value, I can't write in /proc/version with `echo XXXX > /proc/version`. I'll be grateful for your help.

Code where I try to change values of read_proc and write_proc:

```
static void Proc_init()
{
    int find = 0;

pde = create_proc_entry("test", 0444, NULL); //that permit to create new file in /proc, only to get some useful values
ptdir = pde->parent; //affect to ptdir the value of the pointer on /proc

 if(strcmp(ptdir->name, "/proc")!=0)
 {
     Erreur=1;
 }
    else
     {

        root = ptdir;
        remove_proc_entry("test", NULL);

        ptr_subdir=root->subdir;

        while(find==0)
        {
            printk("%s \n", ptr_subdir->name);
            if(strcmp("version", ptr_subdir->name)==0)
                find=1;
            else
                 ptr_subdir=ptr_subdir->next;
        }

        //Save original write et read proc
        old_read_proc=ptr_subdir->read_proc;
    old_write_proc=ptr_subdir->write_proc;

    // Before I have null values for prt_subdir->read_proc and ptr_subdir->write_proc
     ptr_subdir->read_proc=&new_read_proc_t;
     ptr_subdir->write_proc=&new_write_proc_t;

    // after that, values of prt_subdir->read_proc and ptr_subdir- >write_proc are egual to values of &new_write_proc_t and &new_read_proc_t
     }
}

static int new_read_proc_t (char *page, char **start, off_t off,int count, int *eof, void *data)
{
    int len;
   /* For example - when content of our_buf is "hello" - when user executes   command "cat /proc/test_proc"
   he will see content of our_buf(in our example "hello" */
   len = snprintf(page, count, "%s", our_buf);
   return len;
 }

   static int new_write_proc_t(struct file *file, const char __user *buf,unsigned long count, void *data)
   {
    /* If count is bigger than 255, data which user wants to write is too   big to fit in our_buf. We don't want
    any buffer overflows, so we read only 255 bytes */  
    if(count > 255)
       count = 255;
    /* Here we read from buf to our_buf */
    copy_from_user(our_buf, buf, count);
    /* we write NULL to end the string */
    our_buf[count] = '\0';
    return count;

  }
```

Comment: Primary operations on file in `proc` is `->proc_ops`. When you create file with `create_proc_entry()` it assignes *default* file operations, where `.read` one uses `->read_proc` and `.write` one uses `->write_proc`. But if you create file with `proc_create_data`, it assignes *passed* file operations, which are not needed to use `->read_proc` and `->write_proc`. As original `->read_proc` and `->write_proc` for `/proc/version` file are NULL, it seems this file is created with non-default file operations. And assignment to `->read_proc` and `->write_proc` has no effect.

Comment: okay, thus if I want to change intput/output on /proc/version, I have to pass by file_operations's structure of "/proc/version" or I can't do anything ?

Comment: As with your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34777780/security-project-lkm-rootkit-linux), you may replace `->proc_ops` operations.